# User api called on each component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i'm using laravel has backend REST API and React as Frontend.

My problem is many call to user api on each route.

> If i go to `/category` i got an request for user API because i need to have user information like if is an admin; the username; ..., this is normal because i call this api on the App.js i have try to make a conditional statement on the `componentDidMount` to know if i have already the user data in my state, but React return me `infinite loop` with a `this.setState({user: data})`

So my question is can i call the api one time ?
or
Did i need to use Redux to store one time the user data, and consume these data ?

my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Profile from "./pages/Profile";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Administration from "./pages/Administration";
import './assets/main.css'
import './App.css'
import PrivateRoute from "./components/PrivateRoute";
import Category from "./pages/Category";
import Product from "./pages/Product";
import Order from "./pages/Order";
import User from "./pages/User";
import Support from "./pages/Support";
export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            redirectToHome: false,
            isLog: false,
            isAdmin: false,
            user: null,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        if (localStorage.getItem('token')){
            axios.post('auth/me')
                .then((res) => {
                this.setUser(res.data)
                 })
                .catch((err) => {
                    localStorage.removeItem('token')
                })
        }
    }

    setUser = (user) => {
        this.setState({user: user})
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.redirectToHome){
            return <Redirect to={'/'} from={'/logout'} />
        }
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Header user={this.state.user} setUser={this.setUser} />
                </div>
                <div className="mx-10">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Home user={this.state.user} />} />
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={() => <Login setUser={this.setUser} />} />
                        <Route exact path="/profile" component={() => <Profile user={this.state.user}/>} />
                        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin" component={() => <Administration user={this.state.user} />} />
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin/categories" component={() => <Category />} />
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin/products" component={() => <Product />} />
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin/orders" component={() => <Order />} />
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin/users" component={() => <User />} />
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin/supports" component={() => <Support />} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only call the user fetch code once, you will need a place to manage user state to check if it's been called before.
You have two good options. You can use Redux and cache the user value in global state, or you can use Context API and cache in the pass-down state.
Based off the amount of routes you have I would honestly suggest using redux since it's better (in my opinion) for larger apps. Context can get messy since it doesn't enforce a strict separation for actions vs reducers vs current state.

Comment: Okay, thank you for this clear and precise answer. Yes I am building a somewhat complex application.